# Print different part of a page using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following example (simple) HTML file here http://jsfiddle.net/WhupP/2/
The page includes 4 main areas `header`, `left-column`, `righ-column` and `footer`.
Also, it includes 2 `@media` elements `screen` and `print`.

When I print the page, the @media screen{...} styles only gets the call and print the whole page. I know if I want to print for example all areas except `right-column`, I'll add something like `.noprint {display:none;}` to `right-column`

What I wonder is, can I print 1 or 2 areas only (out of those 5) using CSS only? If it's not possible and it requires JS, what is the minimal JS code to get the job done?

For example, when I print the page (ctrl+p or command+p) I want to print area 2 and 3 only. Next time I want to print 2 only, another time I want to print 4 only.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use jQuery to set a class for the items you want to be visible *before* you execute the print action, for example `.visiblePrint` and toggle each time.

You can also catch the print request, if you prefer:
http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/

One example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            printMode = 1;

                var beforePrint = function() {
                        (printMode==3) ? printMode = 1 : printMode++;
                        console.log('Functionality to run before printing.');
                };
                var afterPrint = function() {
                    $('div').removeClass('visiblePrint');
                    switch(printMode) {
                        case 1:
                            $('#print1').addClass('visiblePrint');
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            $('#print2').addClass('visiblePrint');
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $('#print3').addClass('visiblePrint');
                            break;
                    }

                    console.log('Functionality to run after printing');
                };

                if (window.matchMedia) {
                        var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
                        mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
                                if (mql.matches) {
                                        beforePrint();
                                } else {
                                        afterPrint();
                                }
                        });
                }

                $(window).on('beforeprint', beforePrint);
                $(window).on('afterprint', afterPrint);
                /*window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
                window.onafterprint = afterPrint;*/


        }());
    </script>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        div {
            display:none;
        }
        .visiblePrint {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="print1">Messaggio di stampa 1</div>
    <div id="print2">Secondo messaggio di stampa</div>
    <div id="print3">Viva la mamma</div>
</body>
```

Unfortunately, *it's **not** cross browser*, in chrome raise 2 events for time, in firefox don't raise event...

Comment: could you give an example/test with jQuery, I'm that good with it. Thanks